# Scanner class doesn't read the file

Tags: java

Hey my java program has a scanner class in it and it won't read the file. It gives me the following exception " DayCalParser.java:21: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"
I think I should use some sort of IOexception but not sure where to put as this is just a class and there is a no main method.

Also i get an error saying no return statement found

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class DayCalParser {
 private int i = 0;
 private String userdate = "";
 private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 private int day = scan.nextInt();
 private int fday;
 Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("cal.txt"));
 private ArrayList < String > dates = new ArrayList < String > ();


 private void datesFinder(int fday) throws IOException {

  while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
   String line = fileScan.nextLine();
   if (line.contains("DTSTART")) {
    if (line.length() > 25) {
     String year = line.substring(19, 23);
     String month = line.substring(23, 25);
     String dayofmonth = line.substring(25, 27);
     userdate = (dayofmonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);

    }
   }

   if (line.contains("SUMMARY")) {
    String summary = line.substring(12, 13);
    if (summary.equals(fday)) {
     i = i + 1;
     dates.add(userdate);
    }
   }
  } //while
 }

 public String getDates(int fday) {
  datesFinder(fday);
  for (int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) {
   String a = dates.get(j);
   return a;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting with this code?

Comment: add a try-catch block there`public String getDates(int fday){
    **datesFinder(fday);**
    for(int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) {   `

Comment: i am expecting it to scan a file of dates, go through each line get the date and then return done through two seperate methods

Comment: First it has to *compile* properly, only then you can expect it to do anything. The error you mentioned is a *compile* error.

Comment: Are you new to Java? Change your `getDates()` to return a `String`. That's the reason why you are getting "No return statement".

Comment: where is the file located please???... it looks like you are pointing to a wrong place....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check below code, Also modify getDates() function and you can call that function via any class.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {
    private    int i = 0;
    private    String userdate = "";
    private    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    private    int day = scan.nextInt();
    private    int fday;
    private    ArrayList<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();


    private void datesFinder(int fday) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("cal.txt"));
        while (fileScan.hasNext()){
            String line = fileScan.nextLine();
            if (line.contains("DTSTART")){
                if (line.length()>25){
                    String year = line.substring(19,23);
                    String month = line.substring(23,25);
                    String dayofmonth = line.substring(25,27);
                    userdate = (dayofmonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);

                }
            }

            if (line.contains("SUMMARY")) {
                String summary = line.substring(12,13);
                if (summary.equals(fday)){
                    i = i+1;
                    dates.add(userdate);
                }
            }
        }//while
    }

    public String getDates(int fday){
        try {
            datesFinder(fday);
            for(int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) {
                String a = dates.get(j);
                return a;
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.getDates((int) (new Date().getTime()/1000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an Exception, but a Compile Error. The constructor of `Scanner` throws `FileNotFoundException`.
Transfer the initialization inside the `DayCalParser` constructor

```
public DayCalParser() throws FileNotFoundException {
    fileScan = new Scanner(new File("cal.txt"));
}
```

Also, modify your `getDates()` to this:

```
public String getDates(int fday) throws IOException {
    datesFinder(fday);
    for (int j = 0; j < dates.size(); j++) {
        String a = dates.get(j);
        return a;
    }
    return null;
}
```